# Как грамотно подойти к верстке сайта чтобы в дальнейшем было легко его масштабировать?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, архитектура

Здравствуйте, собираюсь разрабатывать большой web проект городской, с большим количеством функционала, но на первой стадии буду делать только верстку. 
Посоветуйте пожалуйста как распределить фалы JS css  и др., как лучше всего поделить стили на библиотеки и т.д. Главная задача в том чтобы потом было легко все заменять как модули.
Есть есть статьи по этому поводу напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Обязательно будет мобильная версия, кроссбраузерность, и нормально отображение на всех экранах

Comment: Если вопрос больше относится к верстке, то тут ваше умение верстать играет большую роль, нежели порядок и распределение подключения стилей. Если у вас нет собственного выработанного подхода, то и вопрос о порядке подключения стилей можно считать бессмысленным.

Comment: Для решения главной задачи - модульности - лучше всего не изобретать велосипед и взять Bootstrap 3 http://getbootstrap.com/ .
Благодаря популярности этого фреймворка можно найти ответы практически на все возникающие при работе с ним вопросы.

Comment: Касательно верстки - вам стоит познакомиться с бэм: http://frontender.info/MindBEMding/

Answer (score 2):

В [данной статье](http://frontender.info/organizing-your-css-code-for-preprocessors/) есть примеры разных подходов (архитектур), с их достоинствами и недостатками, по размещению css (в оригинале scss), js и других файлов в проекте.

Примеры архитектур из статьи:

#### Функциональное распределение

Распределить функциональность на отдельные файлы.

```
_mixins.scss     
_variables.scss
```

#### Распределение «Катана»

Разделить страницы на части и обозначить стили для каждой части индивидуально.

```
/base      
/sections     
  _header.scss     
  _content.scss     
  _footer.scss     
  _sidebar.scss     
  _modals.scss     
/menu     
  _left.scss     
  _right.scss     
  _top.scss     
  _bottom.scss
```

#### Шаблонное или страничное распределение

```
/base    
/templates    
  _category.scss    
  _footer.scss    
  _header.scss    
  _index.scss    
  _page.scss    
  _single.scss
```

#### В терминах веб-дизайна

Как и предполагает название, она предназначена для веб-дизайнеров.
Не использовать папки.

```
_normalize.scss     
_buttons.scss    
_footer.scss     
_grid.scss     
_header.scss    
_icons.scss    
_navigation.scss     
_typography.scss    
screen.scss
```

И так далее... Это может вас натолкнуть на мысли по поводу своей архитектуры.